# Is it effective to use mosquito repellent under clothes?

Tags: clothing, mosquitoes

When wearing long pants and shirt, is it useless to apply a mosquito repellent on the skin under the clothes, or is it effective even under clothes? (for India)

Comment: @CharlieBrumbaugh if it increases effectivity, why not?

Comment: we have mosquitoes that can even sting through your clothes (Socks, T-Shirts on tight spots like your shoulders, even Jeans). Spraying your clothes helps.

Comment: @Peter1807 if you spray your clothes do you still apply on your skin? (India...)

Comment: @Sparkler i cant say for sure, but it sure seemed so. the smell repelled them as soon as they landed on a treated spot, the skin is protected the same way i think, so it should not matter where you spray, as long as it is between your skin and the mosquito.

Answer (score 4):

Hopefully, if your clothes are thick enough, the mosquitos won't be able to bite through. Also as DEET apparently works by messing with the mosquitos [sense of smell](http://phys.org/news/2011-09-deet-insects.html), it won't be as effective because it would first have to go through your clothes.

If they are biting through your clothes, it would be more effective to spray on top of your clothes which has the added benefit of keeping the DEET of your skin.